# In semiconductor physics, how can we know which units to use for Boltzmann's constant?

Tags: semiconductors, physics, units

I'm working through Example 3.9 from Sima Dimitrijev's *Principles of Semiconductor Devices* textbook, and I'm not sure how to know which units to use for *k* in solving for \$v_{th}\$ in part a. The result there is obtainable using the Boltzmann constant *k* with units in J/K. So far in this textbook we've been using *k* with units in eV/K. I need insight into knowing which version of *k* to use, as both versions lead to a final answer with the same units.

[image: Example 3.9 from Sima Dimitrijev's Principles of Semiconductor Devices]

When I divide eV/J in Wolfram|Alpha I get a unitless number \$1.602 \times 10^{-19}\$, which I recognize as the value of electron charge with units in Coulombs. I feel like this is key to understanding my question but I'm not quite there. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [the Wiki page on the electron volt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt#:~:text=Hence%2C%20it%20has%20a%20value,634%C3%9710%E2%88%9219%20J.&text=The%20SI%20unit%20for%20energy%20is%20the%20joule%20(J).).

Comment: If you're handling your units right, both ways will get you to the same answer. ...I hate how they don't teach how to properly handle units in schools.

Comment: @Hearth, the thing is that by using it in terms of eV/K you get a value of 5.7*10^14 m/s. J and eV have the same units so I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: @JakeNixon J and eV have the same *dimension*, not the same units. They *are* two different units.

Comment: @JakeNixon um, while they describe the same thing, an energy, they're not the same unit, so this is just a mistake by you, it seems? \$1\,\text{eV}\ne 1\,\text{J}\$!

Comment: Okay, this must be the first time I'm experiencing the difference between _dimension_ and _unit_. So this takes me back to my original question--what tells me which constant to use when I see the formula for _vth_?

Comment: The thing about constants is that they are constants, and don't change. So, the answer is: you use Boltzmann's constant! No matter in what unit you give it, it's always the same. Just like the density of water stays the same, no matter whether you state it as "gram per cubic millimeter" or "horseshoe crab masses per british pint"

Comment: @MarcusMüller that certainly does make sense. My calculator has two buttons for _k_. One is in eV/K, the other is in J/K. What part of the equation for _vth_ tells me which version to use? Because I get wildly different answers, even if they're the same answer with different units/dimensions.

Comment: None "part" of the equation tells you that, you just need to write down what you're doing, and use the unit you get by using "your" choice of representation. I mean, this is really basic handling of units in calculations!

Comment: Keep track of your units properly and you'll get the right answer. Whether it comes out to V or eV/C doesn't matter to its value, just the number that's attached.

Comment: Remember 1 Joule = 1 Coulomb-Volt.

Comment: This was a pretty dumb misunderstanding of the basics on my part. I had been looking for new unit dimensions to pop up that I could divide out by constants. My error was like thinking that meters per second is identical to meters per hour. Same dimension, different units. Thanks for the help, all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I hate that they don't teach you how to properly handle units in schools...

You know how 1 kJ is 1000 J, or 1 foot is 12 inches? in the same way, 1 J is 6.242·10¹⁸ eV, and 1 eV is 1.602·10⁻¹⁹ (= 1/6.242·10¹⁸) J. The fact that you can convert one to another means they measure the same *dimension*, but the fact that they aren't *equal*, that that conversion factor isn't 1, says that they're different *units*.

Comment: This makes sense and helps me with terminology and understanding. I will admit that this was unintuitive as far as particle physics goes, but your analogy with feet and inches helped me very much.

Comment: @JakeNixon I'm just really surprised this surprised you! I can't remember a time as student when I didn't use units to check whether my calculations made sense – which you can't do if this wasn't clear to you, so things must've been much harder on you (or you're just much smarter)! Either way, you should really get used to keeping the units around in all your calculations, and work a lot on paper; this becomes natural pretty quickly, I promise :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller The reason that this was tricky to me is because sqrt(eV/kg) and sqrt(J/kg) can both be measured in meters per second at the end of the day. The issue lies in the fact that sqrt(1J/1kg) 1 m/s, whereas sqrt(1eV/1kg) is 4.003*10^-10 m/s. I was only looking at the final dimension. I've discussed with my classmates and this wasn't intuitive to anyone at this level. Perhaps it's something to blame on American education.

Comment: yes, they can be *measured in* different units, but they are different units; if you treat the numbers and units separately, you'll notice that pretty quickly :)

Comment: @JakeNixon As I said a few times, American education is really bad in this regard. Even into university I had teachers who didn't properly handle units and it got on my nerves every time.